# Overwrite/delete contents of a text file in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, streamwriter

I'm making a program that writes a list of student objects to a text file and needs to be saved, I could either simply overwrite the contents of the file or delete the contents and rewrite the new list. This is the code I've tried using after some searching,

```
private void saveTSMI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstStudNames.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            SaveFileDia.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";
            if (SaveFileDia.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Clear the file 
                File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDia.FileName, string.Empty);

                //Put all the student info into a string
                foreach (Stud student in StudentList)
                {
                    StudentInfoHolder += "Name: " + student.Name + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Subject: " + student.Subject + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Age: " + student.age + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Grade: " + student.Grade + Environment.NewLine
                    + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                Clipboard.SetText(StudentInfoHolder);
                File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDia.FileName, StudentInfoHolder);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to save");
        }
```

I've seen that `File.WriteAllText()` is meant to overwrite the file but nothing is overwritten when the program is saved.

Comment: What is the relationship between `lstStudNames` and `StudentList`? Are you sure `StudentList` isn't empty?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli `lstStudNames` is the listbox that just holds the student's name, while `StudentList` is the `List<>` that holds the student objects. The code snippet above does write the Student objects to the file, it just doesn't remove any previous students that might have been deleted from `StudentList`.

Comment: I assume that `StudentInfoHolder` is a class member of type String. Seems like it is never reset. Try `StudentInfoHolder = string.Empty` before the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Also, consider using local variable and `String.Format` method

Comment: Let us know for sure what StudentInfoHolder is!

Comment: @yuvin You were correct, `StudentInfoHolder` was never reset. I used it as a backing string to write all of the student properties to the file. I thought it was an issue with the `File.WriteAllText()`! Thanks!

Comment: @ZachRaudebaugh no problem. Posted this as an answer below

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're saving this all to a string that you then put on the clipboard?

Comment: @JimMischel I used it to make sure my formatting of `StudentInfoHolder` was correct before I started writing to the file, just forgot to remove it  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

You have to either reset the `StudentInfoHolder` class member before the `foreach` loop, or even better, use a local string variable in combination with `String.Format` method like this:

```
string studentInfoHolder;

foreach (Stud student in StudentList)
{
    studentInfoHolder += 
        string.Format("Name: {0}\r\nSubject: {1}\r\nAge: {2}\r\nGrade: {3}",
                      student.Name, student.Subject, student.age, student.Grade); 
}

File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDia.FileName, studentInfoHolder);
```

Also, you're right that `File.WriteAllText` overwrites the file content, so this line is useless:

```
File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDia.FileName, string.Empty);
```

**Update**

As @kevin correctly pointed out, it is more efficient to use `StringBuilder` in the loop instead of the string concatenation:

```
StringBuilder studentInfoHolder;

foreach (Stud student in StudentList)
{
    studentInfoHolder.AppendFormat("Name: {0}\r\nSubject: {1}\r\nAge: {2}\r\nGrade: {3}",
                                   student.Name, student.Subject, student.age, student.Grade); 
} 

File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDia.FileName, studentInfoHolder.ToString());
```

Comment: String concatenantion in a loop isn't efficient, better to use a StringBuilder or the TextWriter

Comment: @Kevin Yes, you're right. Just didn't want to overcomplicate :) Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like the following. It avoids opening the file twice, and string concatenation, which is not a great idea with immutable strings.

```
// This line over-writes the file if it exists, or otherwise creates it.
using (TextWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter(SaveFileDia.FileName, append: false))
{
    foreach (Stud student in StudentList)
    {
        fileWriter.WriteLine($"Name: {student.Name}");
        fileWriter.WriteLine($"Subject: {student.Subject}");
        fileWriter.WriteLine($"Age: {student.age}");
        fileWriter.WriteLine($"Grade: {student.Grade}");
        fileWriter.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, I would probably override ToString Student object and just call student.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

There's no good reason to buffer all that in memory before writing it to the file. It's easier to open the file by calling [File.CreateText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx), and then write each line to it, like this:

```
private void saveTSMI_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstStudNames.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing to save");
        return;
    }

    SaveFileDia.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";
    if (SaveFileDia.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return;
    }


    // Create the file (overwrite if it already exists),
    // and write each student record.
    using (var outFile = File.CreateText(SaveFileDia.FileName))
    {
        foreach (Stud student in StudentList)
        {
            outFile.WriteLine("Name: " + student.Name);
            outFile.WriteLine("Subject: " + student.Subject);
            outFile.WriteLine("Age: " + student.age);
            outFile.WriteLine("Grade: " + student.Grade);
        }
    }
}
```

I also refactored your code a bit, reversing the logic on those two tests up front so as to reduce the nesting in your code.

### Update after comment

If you really want a string to contain all that stuff, then you can modify the above to do it pretty easily. Replace the loop that writes to file with this one that uses a [StringWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
    // Create a StringWriter to hold the data, and write each line.
    using (var sWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        foreach (Stud student in StudentList)
        {
            sWriter.WriteLine("Name: " + student.Name);
            sWriter.WriteLine("Subject: " + student.Subject);
            sWriter.WriteLine("Age: " + student.age);
            sWriter.WriteLine("Grade: " + student.Grade);
        }

        // write the data to the file
        StudentInfoHolder = sWriter.ToString();
        File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDia.FileName, StudentInfoHolder);
    }
```

Comment: I never thought about reversing the logic there, I'll have to keep that in mind. I did, however, write everything to `StudentInfoHolder` as well because that information is used elsewhere in the program and it seems cleaner than using all those `outFile.WriteLine()`s again

Comment: Pedantic: StringWriter implements IDisposable, and therefore should be disposed (`using {}`),

Comment: @glenebob Fair enough. Corrected.